# componentWillReceiveProps not firing on Office Panel

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to typeScript and React. Iuse it to develop on SharePoint with Office UI (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric)

I'm trying to update CustomComponent Value when Props linked with Parent internal object is updated.

so :

```
 <NumberField
                label="Quantité Engagement"
                value={this._item.BudgetEngagementDepenseQte}
                returnValue={this.OnQteEngagementChange}
                disabled= {this.props.readOnly}
            />
            <NumberField
                label="Montant total engagement"
                value={this._sumEngagement}
                returnValue= {() => {}}
                disabled={true}
                />
```

for the parent.
the NumberField Contrôl Parse Number value. 
in the first one all works. when I Write in it (input format) my number is parsed with space currency etc. 
in the second one I use it differently. 
he is mapped with a local vairable like the first one but the variable is as source not destination. I use componentWillReceiveProps to rerender this. (I tried these two methods, but not at the same time) :

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        label : this.props.label ? this.props.label : '',
        disabled : this.props.disabled ? this.props.disabled : false,
        value : this.props.value ? this.props.value : ''
    }
    this.componentWillReceiveProps = ((nextProps) => {
        console.log(`nextprops state : ${nextProps.value}`  )
        this.setState({value : nextProps.value})
    }).bind(this);

}

@autobind
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {  
        console.log(`nextprops state : ${nextProps.value}`  )
        this.setState({value : nextProps.value})
}
```

but componentWillReceiveProps never firing. Anyone see where I do a mistake ?

here full NumberField Class :

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { TextField } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField';
import { disableBodyScroll, autobind } from '@uifabric/utilities';
import {CustomFormat} from '../../Tools/CustomFormat'

export class NumberField extends React.Component<{
    label? : string,
    disabled? : boolean,
    value? : string,
    returnValue(value : string)
},{
    label : string,
    disabled : boolean,
    value : string,
}> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            label : this.props.label ? this.props.label : '',
            disabled : this.props.disabled ? this.props.disabled : false,
            value : this.props.value ? this.props.value : ''
        }
        this.componentWillReceiveProps = ((nextProps) => {
            console.log(`nextprops state : ${nextProps.value}`  )
            this.setState({value : nextProps.value})
        }).bind(this);

    }

    @autobind
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {  
            console.log(`nextprops state : ${nextProps.value}`  )
            this.setState({value : nextProps.value})
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <TextField 
            label= {this.state.label}
            disabled={this.state.disabled}
            value={this.state.value}
            onChanged={this.onChanged}/>
        )
    }

    @autobind
    onChanged(value: string) {
        let _value = CustomFormat.ParseNumber(value);
        console.log(_value);
        this.props.returnValue(_value.toString())
        this.setState({ value : CustomFormat.formatNumber(_value) });
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the full NumberField  class? 

Im curious as to why your binding in the constructor.

Comment: I updated My Post. I had the binding in the constructor because I saw it on the net with someone had to do it because in modalDialog. I just tried.

Comment: @cyrilSouied maybe try to remove `@autobind` from componentWillReceiveProps it is not necessary

Comment: Created an answer below.  componentWillReceiveProps will already fire in the correct context.

For onChange, 
@autobinding is not necessary when writing typescript classes with arrow method declaration.

Comment: but my issue si componentWillReceiveProps doesn't fire :(.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with fabric but with typescript, you don't autobinding.

Simply use the `=>` function when declaring class methods, and they will be bound to the class context `this`

```
    import * as React from 'react'
    import { TextField } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField';
    import { CustomFormat } from '../../Tools/CustomFormat'

    interface INumberFieldProps
    {
        readonly label?: string;
        readonly disabled?: boolean;
        readonly value?: string;
        readonly returnValue: ( value: string ) => void;
    }

    interface INumberFieldState
    {
        readonly label: string;
        readonly disabled: boolean;
        readonly value: string;
    }

    export class NumberField extends React.Component<INumberFieldProps, INumberFieldState> {

        constructor( props )
        {
            super( props )
            this.state = {
                label: this.props.label ? this.props.label : '',
                disabled: this.props.disabled ? this.props.disabled : false,
                value: this.props.value ? this.props.value : '',
            }
        }

        public componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps )
        {
            console.log( `nextprops state : ${nextProps.value}` )
            this.setState( { value: nextProps.value } )
        }

        public render()
        {
            return (
                <TextField
                    label={this.state.label}
                    disabled={this.state.disabled}
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChanged={this.onChanged} />
            )
        }

        // Notice the arrow shorthand function declaration 
        private onChanged = ( value: string ) =>
        {
            let _value = CustomFormat.ParseNumber( value );
            console.log( _value );
            this.props.returnValue( _value.toString() )
            this.setState( { value: CustomFormat.formatNumber( _value ) } );
        }

    }
```

Comment: when I do What you Wrote I have an error  :  error TS2605: JSX element type 'NumberField' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.

Comment: <= mistake It works but as the @Autobind. my issue still occure.

Comment: Issue as in componentWillReceiveProps is not firing? Remember the componentWillReceiveProps will not fire unless props have changed after the component has mounted.

Comment: Yes, but when I change props, Nothing occure in component. (event not finring)

Comment: That's really strange. Are you sure you don't have a 'shouldComponentUpdate' part of your parent component or something? We would need to see the parent component code as well.